# How to autoplay expo-av video on focus in flatlist

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist, react-native-video, expo-av

The app I'm making consist pictures and videos sharing, and my goal is to autoplay the video once it is focused, also pauses it after it is out of the view inside the FlatList.

**Here is a demo of what it looks like now:**
[image]

**I have 2 questions with it:**

1. How can I achieve my goal? Please help!
2. If the video autoplays when it becomes fully visible to the user, but the problem is, as seen in my demo, 2 videos are both in the view and fully visible, so which one should I play then?

Comment: I'm curious about this one, were you able to find a solution for it?

Comment: Not yet, still waiting

Answer (score 0):

I had your question in my mind since you posted it, the way you can implement it is with the help of the following library:
https://github.com/changey/react-native-component-inview
which you can set the autoplay/ is playing according to what's in view